# Install gdal-java on windows 7

Tags: java, environment-variables, swig, gdal

I tried installing gdal with java bindings via [this](http://download.gisinternals.com/release.php) site (I used release-1600-x64-gdal-1-11-1-mapserver-6-4-1 and unpacked it to C:\GDAL) Then I executed SDKShell.bat and it created these environment variables(all pathes exist):

```
 PATH "C:\GDAL\bin;C:\GDAL\bin\gdal\python\osgeo;C:\GDAL\bin\proj\apps;C:\GDAL\bin\gdal\apps;C:\GDAL\bin\ms\apps;C:\GDAL\bin\gdal\csharp;C:\GDAL\bin\ms\csharp;C:\GDAL\bin\curl;C:\GDAL\"
 GDAL_DATA "C:\GDAL\bin\gdal-data"
 GDAL_DRIVER_PATH "C:\GDAL\bin\gdal\plugins"
 PYTHONPATH "C:\GDAL\bin\gdal\python;C:\GDAL\bin\ms\python"
 PROJ_LIB "C:\GDAL\bin\proj\SHARE"
```

than I included gdal.jar, which is located in C:\GDAL\bin\gdal\java . The dlls gdalconstjni, gdaljni, ogrjni, osrjni are in the same folder. When I try to run [gdalinfo.java](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/java/apps/gdalinfo.java) in eclipse (Luna) I get this exception:

```
Native library load failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdaljni in java.library.path
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister()V
    at org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister(Native Method)
    at org.gdal.gdal.gdal.AllRegister(gdal.java:499)
    at wmsRasterToGeojsonVector.gdalinfo.main(gdalinfo.java:90)
```

I read that putting the environment variables in the run configuration (in Eclipse) should help but it didn't.
I have Windows 7 64Bit
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to put other *jni files into the java path. Might a solution.